# Error on string index out of range: python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have made a simple script to find urls in strings, however i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Desktop\urlformstringtest.py", line 17, in <module>
    url = url + string[a]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

here is my code:

```
while True:
url = "No Url"
string = input("What is your string: ")
string = string + "             "

for x in string:
    if x == "h":
        a = string.find(x)
        if string[a + 1] == "t" and string[a + 2] == "t" and string[a + 3] == "p" and string[a + 4] == "s":
            a = a + 4
            url = "http"
            while True:
                a = a + 1
                if a == " ":
                    break
                    break
                url = url + string[a]
print(url)
```

i have only been programing a few weeks so dont use complicated language please

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It is very important in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your code doesn't make any sense:

```
while True:
    a = a + 1 # increment index
    if a == " ": # it's an integer, this will *never* be True
        break # so this never happens
        break # why 'break' again?! This line would never run either
    url = url + string[a] # index is off the end of the string -> IndexError
```

The minimal fix to stop the error is:

```
if string[a] == " ":
```

i.e. actually test the *character at that position*, not the integer index.

However, I think what you're trying to do is switch from `'https'` to `'http'` and stop at the first space, in which case the following line will do the job:

```
string = string.replace("https", "http").split()[0]
```

`.replace` will just quietly do nothing if `'https'` isn't in the `string`.